# How to disable autofocus from username field in Django's UserCreationForm?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, autofocus

I am using the `UserCreationForm` class to create a signup page in my Django app.

Here is my code that defines my `SingUpForm`:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = ...
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username",
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            ...
            "autofocus": False,
            ...
        }))
    password1 = ...
    password2 = ...
```

Despite the `autofocus` attribute being set to `False`, when I open the form in my browser the focus is still on the `username` field.

How can I disable it?

Comment: should't ve been like this: 

field = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': 'autofocus'}))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The autofocus is overridden in the `__init__` of `UserCreationForm` (see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a6291394256aa758d74eec9ce0cfae8aea6475f2/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L108)).
You should try to use the same technique by adding `__init__` in your `SignUpForm` :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': False})
```